# istringstream, whats happening to num1 & num2 here?

Tags: c++, istringstream

I'm going through a C++ book (cpluplusnotes for professionals), and got to this example and was wondering whats happening with num1 / 2 here and how the in(xxxx) is affecting it ?

Thankyou !

```
`#include <sstream>
...
std::istringstream in("10 010 10 010 10 010");
int num1, num2;
in >> std::oct >> num1 >> num2;
std::cout << "Parsing \"10 010\" with std::oct gives: " << num1 << ' ' << num2 << '\n';
// Output: Parsing "10 010" with std::oct gives: 8 8
in >> std::dec >> num1 >> num2;
std::cout << "Parsing \"10 010\" with std::dec gives: " << num1 << ' ' << num2 << '\n';
// Output: Parsing "10 010" with std::oct gives: 10 10
in >> std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::basefield) >> num1 >> num2;
std::cout << "Parsing \"10 010\" with autodetect gives: " << num1 << ' ' << num2 << '\n';
// Parsing "10 010" with autodetect gives: 10 8
std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios_base::hex |
std::ios_base::uppercase |
std::ios_base::showbase) << 42 << '\n';
// Output: OX2A`
```

Also to note i understand Oct, dec , hex and all that i just dont get how num1/2 have been assigned values off the in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::oct` and `std::dec` tell the stream how to convert the string to an integer.

If one of them is set, then `num1` and `num2` are read as if they were written in base 8 or 10.

When none is set, `10` is read as decimal (default for digit-strings not stariting with 0) and `010` is read as octal (default for digit-strings starting with 0).

Comment: Good answer, but do you have a reference for your claim about `010` being read as octal by default?

Comment: See [`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) and [`std::num_get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get)

Comment: Ahhhh ok that makes sense i misread the input. Thanks heaps mate !